# How do I compose multiple monads? IO / Future and maybe with even State and Option

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

I'm trying to compose monads in Scala doing some requests to server.
here is the code snippet that I'm using. I try not to use flatmap as possible only using for comprehension as well. any ideas? I know using Monad Transformers, but I don't know how to compose multiple monads. can anyone help me out?

```
for {
  session <- getSession(ticker) //IO[Future[Response]]
  crumbF = session.flatMap(response => Future(parseCrumb(response.body)))
  cookiesF = session.flatMap(response => Future(response.cookies))
  crumb = Await.result(crumbF, 5 seconds) // Future[String]
  cookies = Await.result(cookiesF, 5 seconds) //Future[Seq[Cookies]]
  data <- getData(ticker, startDate, endDate, interval, crumb, cookies.head) // IO[Future[Response]]
  stocksF = data.flatMap { response =>
    import DefaultBodyReadables._
    Future {
      StockDf.mapDataToDf(response.body)
    }
  }
} yield stocksF
```

Comment: Monads in general don't compose. Transformers are special cases that do, in some sense, compose. You can stack several transformers to compose several monads.

Comment: Are you trying to compose monads, i.e. put one monad into another, like a `Future` with an `Option` inside, or are you trying to work with different monads in one `for` comprehension?

Comment: It is not clear that `for` is the right way to go with this code. All those assignments and `Await` statements would be clearer if they were written out as normal code. In the end this is just a `map` nested in a `flatMap` and would probably look clearer written out that way. And why call `flatMap` and wrap the result in a `Future` rather than just calling `map`?

Answer (score 3):

So a few things.

If you launch futures inside a for comprehension then they will run in sequence rather than in parallel - if this is your intention then fine. If not then instantiate them outside the for comprehension.

You cannot mix monadic contexts inside a for comprehension.

```
// Yes
for {
  a <- Some(5)
  b <- Some(10)
} yield 5 * 10

// No
for {
  a <- Some(5)
  b <- Future(10)
} yield 5 * 10
```